# Case statement gives error cound not convert 'ABC' to a float8

Tags: sql, case, vertica

I am trying to run below sql statement but getting could not convert to a float. By default return type of case is taking as float. Tried casting it to varchar in Row_num , Name but didn't help. Any help be helpful.
Database = Vertica

```
SELECT 
Name,
ID,
row_num,

(Case when Row_num  = 1 Then Name  END) +
(Case When Row_num  = 2 Then Name  END)
FROM table ;
```

Comment: what is the data type of Name?

Comment: In other words, if "name" is "Little" and "Foot", what do you expect as a result when you sum those two strings? Did you, by any chance, mean to concatenate them? If so, concatenation operator is double pipe sign `||`, not `+`.

Comment: Oracle or Vertica? Do not include tags for databases you don't use.

Comment: Name is Varchar

Comment: Vertica. Sql hold good both for oracle and Vertica that's why tagged both. Concat will not help here as it will give Null value for Row_num 2 while concatenating

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
SELECT 
Name,
ID,
row_num,
(SELECT Name FROM table WHERE Row_num = 1) +
(SELECT Name FROM table WHERE Row_num = 2) AS ConcatNames
FROM table ;
```

Comment: End Goal is to Concat Result of Case statement 1 and 2. Limitation with Concat operator is Lets say row_num = 1 , Name = AB and row_num = 2 , Name = BC . While using concat for CASE WHEN Row_num  = 2 THEN Name ELSE '' END it will give null as output. instead of AB||BC

Comment: In that case what I would use is something like this (edited answer)

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate strings in Vertica, use `||`:

```
SELECT Name, ID, row_num,
       ((Case when Row_num  = 1 Then Name  END) ||
        (Case When Row_num  = 2 Then Name  END)
       )
FROM table ;
```

I'm not quite sure what this is supposed to do, because one or both `case` expressions will return `NULL`.